# linux:use clone's function performance without use clone() or sys_clone, can I do that?

Tags: linux, clone, sys

I would like to try execute clone's performance, but without calling clone()  in linux(error said library not implemented in that structure).

I try to check sys_clone but found it impossible since the parameters are some registers information;

Also tried to use pthread to mimic clone's performance but since:
pthread_create(&tid, NULL,foo,para)
and in the function foo
if I use
void* foo(void* para){
execvp(...)
}
execvp can't be executed since pthread creates thread and thread can't call that exec.

Anyone can tell me how I can achieve clone without using system call clone or whether I can do that in pthread?
Or Is there any other function in linux that call sys_clone without using the register parameter but the clone_flags?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What are you really trying to accomplish here, and why can't you use the `clone()` call to do it?